# Mysql count with join from two tables for one user-id

Tags: php, mysql

i want to return follower and following numbers for just one user_id from existing two tables which one is users and the other one is follow:

my code is here

```
SELECT users.id,
       users.name,
       COUNT(folow.following),
       COUNT(folow.follower)
FROM users
JOIN folow ON folow.following = users.id
WHERE users.id = '$other' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: could you post your table structure also ?

Comment: For me this should be made with sub selects. I think joins are not the best option in this case.

Comment: what problem you are getting.

Comment: it is good to have only one query i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably simplest to use correlated subqueries here:

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM folow WHERE following = users.id) followers,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM folow WHERE follower  = users.id) following
FROM   users
WHERE  id = ?
```

Comment: right.. "SELECT users.name,COUNT(folow.following) AS following,COUNT(folow.follower) AS follower FROM users,folow  
WHERE users.id = '$other' LIMIT 1"